# What is value of integration of step function which has complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, step-function

$$\int_{-a}^{a}dx\,  \theta(\sqrt{x}) = \,?$$

At this calculation, I can do anything in the range of $-a < x < 0$. How can I do that calculation?

Comment: How is $\theta$ defined? Have you tried something?

Comment: \theta is \int^{x}_{-\infty}\delta(s)ds

Comment: how can i write to real symbol?